# import two python module from two different directory

Tags: python

My file structure like

```
    Myfolder/
           main/
              -main.py
           folder1/
              -file1.py
           folder2/
              -file2.py
```

I call file1.py with

```
sys.path.insert(0, '../file1')
import file1
```

that work, but i dont know how to do it again for file2.py.
please help

Comment: You should educate yourself on how Python imports work, what the PYTHONPATH is and what `__init__.py` is for.

Comment: what does `how to do it again for file2.py` mean?

Comment: it's work  to import file1 but i try insert with file2 it show no such file or directory. i need to import file2 too

Comment: @KlausD. Thank for your advice

Comment: This link may be useful to you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way without inserting in the sys path.

```
import .folder2.file2
import .folder1.file1
```